# Stored procedure tutorial

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2013

Excuse me if not very good english.

I'm starting to learn sql language, and I have difficulty with one of the basics I guess.

I'm creating a table in my visual studio sql project:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table]
(
[Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
[w] VARCHAR(50) NULL, 
[p] VARCHAR(50) NULL, 
[g] VARCHAR(50) NULL, 
[m] VARCHAR(50) NULL
)
```

I think I got it right, it should store 4 strings per entry.

Now, the next part is I want to create a stored procedure like so

```
procedure(string, letter)
```

String is a value from m field in the table, letter is one of 3 letters (w,g,p) and I want it to find me the m entry in the table and display the value the w g or p field has.

So if I have entry that has Abra in the m field, and cadabra in g field, and I write procedure(Abra, g) I want it to display me cadabra.

**EDIT:**

Will this work?

```
Create  PROCEDURE p(

 @n_m VARCHAR(50)
 @o_j CHAR

 )
 AS
 BEGIN

 SELECT w FROM Table WHERE m=@n_m AND @o_j='w'

 SELECT p FROM Table WHERE m=@n_m AND @o_j='p'

 SELECT g FROM Table WHERE m=@n_m AND @o_j='g'
 END
```

Comment: Have you tried it? It looks like it should work...

Comment: Are you sure that the 3 select are what you want? Take a look at the Select-Case operator from sql: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cy37t14y.aspx I think this is what you want ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can create the stored procedure like this:

```
CREATE PROC spProcedure
    @n_m VARCHAR(50),
    @o_j CHAR
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT
        CASE @o_j
            WHEN 'w' THEN w
            WHEN 'p' THEN p
            WHEN 'g' THEN G
        END
    FROM [dbo].[Table]
    WHERE [m] = @n_m
END
```

After inserting the following row:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table] ([Id], [g], [m]) VALUES (1, 'cadabra', 'Abra');
```

.. the procedure outputs 'cadabra' when executing the procedure in the following way:

```
EXEC spProcedure @n_m = 'Abra', @o_j = 'g'
```

The procedure I've created uses only one SELECT-statement. As you can see the SELECT-statement contains an CASE-expression. The CASE-expression checks whether the @o_j parameter is 'w', 'p' or 'g', when the value is 'w' the CASE will output the w column of the table in the SELECT-statement. The WHERE-statement makes sure that the value of m in the SELECT-statement is equal to @n_m.

You can read more about the CASE-expression right here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx